# Choice of laptop and processor for webserver

Tags: laptop, processor, web-server

So I am trying to decide on a laptop which will run a ubuntu apache webserver, which does not break the bank.

I am using the webserver as a kind of quiz machine with 50 wireless clients connected concurrently answering questions and submitting answers. Nothing heavy like streaming videos, but each user requests is around 10-30 kb, static pages, one question per page, one jpeg. The users could be using the server all at once.

Anyway, I hear that RAM is very important over anything else but because I am using it for what I am trying to do, I am making sure that I have enough RAM and a SSD drive. The model I am thinking about Lenovo L460:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOQO7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O7Uj.png

But the question I want to ask is if the current processor is too weak to handle my project and I should upgrade to the intel core i5 to maximize performance?

Comment: Asking if X processor is too weak qualifies as tech support, which we don't deal with here. However, you've got a good basis for a recommendation request here - instead of asking "is X too weak", if you ask "I want an Ubuntu laptop with plenty of RAM and an SSD", then we can recommend something that fits your requirements.

Comment: Strangely, Superuser told me to come here!

Comment: That'll be because SU doesn't know our scope very well. However, you're very close to being on topic here.

Comment: @peteubuntu As ArtOfCode said, your question can absolutely be reopened if you reword it, and I encourage you to do this because it's a great question.